# Android RecyclerView with blank data?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, cardview

I have a very strange issue with a RecyclerView. It shows a card with missing info, although in the adapter it receives an element of the list.

How it is now ?

[image: card without content]

How it should be  ?

[image: card with content]

I have a feeling that sometimes it flashes data for a moment, but eventually this is still without text.

I attach XML files and some code, if someone has any ideas what is going on ?

***Fragment XML***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="controlViewModel"
            type="com.company.app.ui.viewmodels.SearchViewModel"
            />
    </data>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.fragments.SearchFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_device_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/device_item" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="@string/str_search_button_text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/rv_device_list"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rv_device_list"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

***Item XML***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="deviceItem"
            type="com.company.app.domain.entity.Device" />
    </data>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/purple_200"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@{deviceItem.name}"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:text="Device 1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_address"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="@{deviceItem.address}"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:text="192.168.1.12:8000" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

*** Fragment code ***

```
private var ioScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
private var coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)

override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false)
        _binding = FragmentSearchBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewModelFactory = SearchViewModelFactory(repository)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(
            this,
            viewModelFactory).get(SearchViewModel::class.java)
        binding.controlViewModel = viewModel
        binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
        binding.btnSearch.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.clearDevices()
            ioScope.launch {
                viewModel.searchImplementation()
                if (repository.getSize() >0)
                    System.out.println(repository.getSize())
                    //binding.rvDeviceList.adapter?.notifyItemInserted()
            }
        }

       initRecyclerView()

        }



    private suspend fun addDevice(item:Device) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main)
         {repository.addDevice(item)
        }
    }

    private fun initRecyclerView()
        {
            binding.rvDeviceList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext().applicationContext)
            displayDeviceFound()
        }
    private fun displayDeviceFound(){
        viewModel.deviceList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            Log.i("Adapter",it.toString())
            adapter = DeviceListAdapter(it, this)
            binding.rvDeviceList.adapter = adapter
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
        )
    }
```

**** Viewmodel code****

```
class SearchViewModel(private val repository: DeviceRepositoryImpl): ViewModel(), Observable {

    var notEmpty : Boolean = false

    var devices = repository.getDeviceList()

    var isSearchServiceBound : Boolean = false

    private var _deviceList = MutableLiveData<List<Device>>()
    val deviceList: LiveData<List<Device>>
        get() = _deviceList

    init {
        _deviceList = devices as MutableLiveData<List<Device>>

    }

    @Bindable
    val name = MutableLiveData<String>()

    @Bindable
    val address = MutableLiveData<String>()


    fun initialization() {
        repository.updateList()
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
    }

    override fun addOnPropertyChangedCallback(callback: Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback?) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun removeOnPropertyChangedCallback(callback: Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback?) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    fun addDevice(item: Device) {
        repository.addDevice(item)
        repository.updateList()
    }

    fun clearDevices() {
        repository.clearList()
    }



    suspend fun searchImplementation() : Unit {
        try {
            //Open a random port to send the package
            val socket = DatagramSocket(8899, InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0"))
            var timer = 0
            do {
                System.out.println(">>>Ready to receive broadcast packets!")
                //Receive a packet
                val recvBuf : ByteArray = ByteArray(25);
                var packet: DatagramPacket = DatagramPacket(recvBuf, recvBuf.size);
                socket.receive(packet);
                //Packet received
                System.out.println(">>>Discovery packet received from: " + packet.getAddress().getHostAddress())
                //System.out.println(">>>Packet received data: " + packet.getData().toString())
                val bytes = (packet.data)
                EventBus.getDefault().post(DeviceFoundEvent(bytes, packet.getAddress().hostAddress, "8899"))
                //var item = Device(String(bytes), packet.getAddress().getHostAddress(), "8899"
                delay(100)
                timer++
                } while (timer!=10)
                notEmpty = repository.getSize() >0

        }
        catch (e: Exception) {
            System.out.print(e)
        }
        finally {
        }
    }


}
```

**** Adapter code ****

```
class DeviceListAdapter (newList:List<Device>, private val parentFragment : Fragment): RecyclerView.Adapter<DeviceItemViewHolder>(){

    private var list = newList

    set(value) {
        field=value
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DeviceItemViewHolder {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder")
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding : DeviceItemBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            layoutInflater,
            R.layout.device_item,
            parent,
            false)
        return DeviceItemViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewholder: DeviceItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder")
        viewholder.bind(list[position])
        viewholder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            launchControlFragment(list[position].name, list[position].ipAddress, list[position].port)
        }
        viewholder.binding.executePendingBindings()

    }

    override fun onViewRecycled(viewholder: DeviceItemViewHolder) {
        super.onViewRecycled(viewholder)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }

    private fun launchControlFragment (name: String, address:String, port:String) {
        val action = SearchFragmentDirections.actionSearchFragmentToControlFragment()
        action.name =name
        action.address = address
        action.port=port
        findNavController(parentFragment).navigate(action)

    }

    companion object {
        const val  TAG = "DeviceListAdapter:"
    }

}
```

**** ViewHolder

```
class DeviceItemViewHolder(
    val binding: DeviceItemBinding
    ): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){

        fun bind(deviceItem: Device){
            binding.tvName.text = deviceItem.name
            Log.d(TAG, deviceItem.name)
            binding.tvAddress.text = deviceItem.address
            Log.d(TAG, deviceItem.address)
        }

    companion object
    const val TAG = "DeviceItemViewHolder"
    }
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: same here, I am using gridlayout manager. It flashes the data and then becomes empty. Did you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In your `DeviceItemViewHolder` You should be using the `Databinding` to bind your data to the layout, however, you're setting the `TextView` text attribute by calling

```kotlin
fun bind(deviceItem: Device){
   binding.tvName.text = deviceItem.name
   Log.d(TAG, deviceItem.name)
   binding.tvAddress.text = deviceItem.address
   Log.d(TAG, deviceItem.address)
}
```

You should send the whole object to the layout, and it will take care of binding these attribute to the layout elements.

```kotlin
fun bind(deviceItem: Device){
   binding.apply {
      this.deviceItem = deviceItem
      executePendingBindings()
   }
}
```